# Scraping data from website to Excel using a macro...lost

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am totally new to this but here is my scope.
I am running a macro to pull data from a business system.
After this info is pulled, I want a macro to take certain fields, put them into a website form, click submit and then scrape and paste certain data results back into excel.
Everything works minus the scraping and pasting back into excel.

Help please!

I have searched all over stack overflow and watched vids to try and figure out what I need to do but I must be misunderstanding something.

```
Sub Track()
Range("B2").Select

'This should call to PT and deliver tracking info

Dim IE As Object
Dim tbl As Object, td As Object



 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'Set IEapp = 
 InternetExplorer
 IE.Visible = True

      IE.Navigate "https://www.partstown.com/track-my-order"
      With IEapp
          Do
          DoEvents
          Loop Until IE.readyState = 4



'Input PO and zip
 Call IE.Document.getElementById("orderNo").SetAttribute("value", 
 "4500969111")
'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
 Call IE.Document.getElementById("postalCode").SetAttribute("value", 
 "37040")
 IE.Document.forms(7).Submit

 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:09")

'this is where i am stuck. I know this isnt right but tried to piece it 
 together
 Set elemCollection = IE.Document.getelElementsByTagname("table.account- 
 table details _tc_table_highlighted")

 For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)
 For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
    For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = 
 elemCollection(t).Rows.Cells(c).innertext
 Next c
 Next r
 Next t

 End With


 End Sub
```

Here is what I want it to pull:
Shipping column
QTY ordered
QTY shipped Product
And to display in a linear fashion:
Shipping, QTY ordered, QTY shipped, Product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Internet Explorer:

I have made this a little more verbose than usual so you can see each step.

Key things:

1) proper page loads waits with `While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend`

2) selecting elements by id where possible. The `#` is a css [id selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors). [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) are applied by [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of .document and retrieve the first element in the page which matches the specified pattern

3) a timed loop is needed to wait for results to be present

4) the order qty etc info is a newline divided string. It seemed easiest to split on these newlines and then access individual items from the resultant array by index

5) I order, per your specification, the results in an array and write that array out in one go to the sheet

6) The "."  is a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) in `.order-history__item-descript--min` i.e. return the first element with `class` of `order-history__item-descript--min`

7) The [x=y] is an [attribute = value selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) in `[data-label=Shipping]` i.e. return the first element with `data-label` attribute having value `Shipping`

8) The combination of `.details-table a` is using a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), " ", to specify I want `a` tag elements that have a parent with class `.details-table`

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub RetrieveInfo()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, ele As Object, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.partstown.com/track-my-order"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#orderNo").Value = "4500969111"
            .querySelector("#postalCode").Value = "37040"
            .querySelector("#orderLookUpForm").submit  
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim shipping As String, order As String, items() As String
        With .document
            t = Timer
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = .querySelector("[data-label=Shipping]")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While ele Is Nothing

            If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

            shipping = ele.innerText
            order = .querySelector(".order-history__item-descript--min").innerText
            items = Split(order, vbNewLine)

            Dim qtyOrdered As Long, qtyShipped As String, product As String

            qtyOrdered = CLng(Replace$(items(0), "Qty Ordered: ", vbNullString))
            qtyShipped = CLng(Replace$(items(1), "Qty Shipped: ", vbNullString))
            product = .querySelector(".details-table a").Title

            Dim results()
            results = Array(shipping, qtyOrdered, qtyShipped, product)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(results) + 1) = results

        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

If new to HTML please look at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML

If new to css selectors please look at:

https://flukeout.github.io/

---

### XMLHTTP:

The whole thing can also be done with [XHR](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/). This is much faster than opening a browser.

[XHR:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

> Use XMLHttpRequest (XHR) objects to interact with servers. You can
>   retrieve data from a URL without having to do a full page [render]

In this case I do an initial `GET` request to the landing page to retrieve the 
`CSRFToken` to use in my re-enactment of the `POST` request the page makes to the server when you manually input data and press submit. You get the data you  want in the server response. I pass a query string in the body of the POST send line
`.send "orderNo=4500969111&postalCode=37040&CSRFToken=" & csrft` ; you can see your parameters there.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, csrft As String  '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.partstown.com", False
        .send

        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        csrft = html.querySelector("[name=CSRFToken]").Value

        .Open "POST", "https://www.partstown.com/track-my-order", False
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.partstown.com/track-my-order"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"
        .send "orderNo=4500969111&postalCode=37040&CSRFToken=" & csrft

        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim shipping As String, order As String, items() As String

    shipping = html.querySelector("[data-label=Shipping]").innerText
    order = html.querySelector(".order-history__item-descript--min").innerText
    items = Split(order, vbNewLine)

    Dim qtyOrdered As Long, qtyShipped As String, product As String

    qtyOrdered = CLng(Replace$(items(0), "Qty Ordered: ", vbNullString))
    qtyShipped = CLng(Replace$(items(1), "Qty Shipped: ", vbNullString))
    product = html.querySelector(".details-table a").Title

    Dim results()
    results = Array(shipping, qtyOrdered, qtyShipped, product)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(results) + 1) = results
End Sub
```

---

**Example of loop:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, csrft As String, lastRow As Long, sourceValues() '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    sourceValues = ws.Range("B2:D" & lastRow).Value
    Dim results()
    ReDim results(1 To UBound(sourceValues, 1), 1 To 4)
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.partstown.com", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        csrft = html.querySelector("[name=CSRFToken]").Value
        Stop
        For i = LBound(sourceValues, 1) To UBound(sourceValues, 1)
            If sourceValues(i, 1) <> vbNullString And sourceValues(i, 3) <> vbNullString Then
                DoEvents
                .Open "POST", "https://www.partstown.com/track-my-order", False
                .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.partstown.com/track-my-order"
                .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
                .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                .setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
                .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
                .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"
                .send "orderNo=" & sourceValues(i, 1) & "&postalCode=" & sourceValues(i, 3) & "&CSRFToken=" & csrft

                html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

                Dim shipping As String, order As String, items() As String

                shipping = html.querySelector("[data-label=Shipping]").innerText
                order = html.querySelector(".order-history__item-descript--min").innerText
                items = Split(order, vbNewLine)

                Dim qtyOrdered As Long, qtyShipped As String, product As String

                qtyOrdered = CLng(Replace$(items(0), "Qty Ordered: ", vbNullString))
                qtyShipped = CLng(Replace$(items(1), "Qty Shipped: ", vbNullString))
                product = html.querySelector(".details-table a").Title

                results(i, 1) = shipping
                results(i, 2) = qtyOrdered
                results(i, 3) = qtyShipped
                results(i, 4) = product
            End If
            'Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        Next
    End With
    'results written out from row 2 column E
    ws.Cells(2, 5).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub
```

Comment: I did sir! I am sorry I didn't reply earlier. When I had made that post I was up about 25 hours trying to figure it out.Thank you very very much. I appreciate your help. The only thing I need to figure out, which I have been looking into is how to change the code (XMLHTTP) to pull data from the excel sheet and not singular data (pull orderNo from cell B2 and postalCode from D2), offset and loop.

Comment: It did for exactly as I had asked for help with, I accidentally posted my first comment too early. I do need to do more work to get the code to look to excel to find the values until values = "" would i be able to find this info on the links you so nicely added to your post? Once again I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: I think you are perhaps referring to performing this in a loop picking up values for orderNo  and postcode from the worksheet?

Comment: which version do you want ? The xmlhttp or the internet explorer?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! And absolutely I will accept the answer, you have been very helpful!

Comment: Do you have your orderNo and postcode in adjacent columns? For example columns A and B? And are there any empty cells in that range?

Comment: They are actually in B for orderNo and postalCode is in D. I imagine that I could move the data around if that makes it easier. There are some with empty postalCodes, I was hoping to just have those as ignored

Comment: Ok so only consider B if D is not empty? That is fine. I will update tonight.

Comment: Awesome!! you are my new hero!

Comment: loop example added/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am sorry that it took me a long time to get back to you. Had death in family and just craziness happening. I appreciate your help. I have another question regarding this but I will create a new post around it. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry to hear that. See you at the new post.